# How do I generate a random name without repeating?

Tags: flutter, dart

**I want to generate a random name without repeating the name**

**I tried a lot but did not get any result**

**Is there a way for me to do it**

In fact, I've tried a lot on whether a variable is a number, The operation was completed successfully,

But I encountered difficulties in case the variable is of type name

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'dart:math';

class RandomName extends StatefulWidget {
static const id = 'RandomName';
const RandomName({super.key});

@override
State<RandomName> createState() => _RandomNameState();
}

class _RandomNameState extends State<RandomName> {
List<String> names = [];
Random random = Random();
TextEditingController nameController = TextEditingController();
```

This is the second part:

```
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
return Scaffold(
  backgroundColor: Colors.grey[900],
  appBar: AppBar(),
  body: Column(
    children: [
      Expanded(
          child: ListView.builder(
              itemCount: names.length,
              itemBuilder: ((context, index) {
                return Dismissible(
                  key: UniqueKey(),
                  onDismissed: (direction) {
                    setState(() {
                      names.removeAt(index);
                    });
                  },
                  child: ListTile(
                    title: Text(names[index]),
                  ),
                );
              }))),
      Expanded(
        child: Padding(
          padding: EdgeInsets.all(20.0),
          child: Column(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.end,
            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
            children: <Widget>[
              Text(
                "add new",
                style: TextStyle(
                    color: Colors.grey.shade500,
                    fontWeight: FontWeight.w600),
              ),
              Row(
                children: <Widget>[
                  Expanded(
                    child: TextField(
                      autocorrect: false,
                      autofocus: true,
                      maxLines: 1,
                      cursorColor: Colors.grey.shade500,
                      cursorWidth: 1.5,
                      textInputAction: TextInputAction.done,
                      keyboardAppearance: Brightness.dark,
                      style: TextStyle(
                          fontSize: 20, color: Colors.grey.shade500),
                      textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                      keyboardType: TextInputType.name,
                      controller: nameController,
                      decoration: const InputDecoration(
                        border: InputBorder.none,
                        contentPadding:
                            EdgeInsets.only(top: 10, bottom: 10),
                        isDense: true,
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                  ElevatedButton(
                    child: Text('Add'),
                    onPressed: () {
                      addToList();
                      nameController.clear();
                    },
                  )
                ],
              ),
              Builder(
                  builder: (context) => ElevatedButton(
                      child: Text('Get Random Name'),
                      onPressed: () {
                        showAlertDialog(context);
                      }))
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    ],
  ),
);
}
```

This is the third part:

The code is required to print four random names without repeating inside "Text"

```
Future<void> showAlertDialog(BuildContext context) {
return showDialog<void>(
    context: context,
    builder: (BuildContext context) {
      return AlertDialog(
        content: Container(
          margin: const EdgeInsets.all(8),
          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(5),
          width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width / 1.3,
          height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height / 3.5,
          color: Colors.grey.shade900,
          alignment: Alignment.center,
          child: Row(
            children: <Widget>[
              Text(
                names[random.nextInt(names.length)],
                textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                style: const TextStyle(fontSize: 15),
              ),
              Text(
                names[random.nextInt(names.length)],
                textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                style: const TextStyle(fontSize: 15),
              ),
              Text(
                names[random.nextInt(names.length)],
                textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                style: const TextStyle(fontSize: 15),
              ),
              Text(
                names[random.nextInt(names.length)],
                textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                style: const TextStyle(fontSize: 15),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
        backgroundColor: Colors.grey.shade900,
      );
    });
    }

 void addToList() {
  if (nameController.text.isNotEmpty) {
   setState(() {
    names.add(nameController.text);
  });
  }
  }
  }
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question to show what you have tried

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you want to generate names when you click on the button, you effectively want to create a copy of the list and give it a shuffle inside the `showAlertDialog()` function.

```
List<String> namesCopy = List.from(names)..shuffle();
```

Replace `Row()` with `Wrap()` to prevent text overflowing to the right.

```
Wrap(
  spacing: 8.0, // gap between adjacent chips
  runSpacing: 4.0, // gap between lines
```

And finally, to prevent showing duplicates, generate a list of widgets that takes a count of 4 or the length of names, whichever is lower.

```
min(4, namesCopy.length)
```

The resulting `showAlertDialog()` function should look like this:

```dart
  Future<void> showAlertDialog(BuildContext context) {
    List<String> namesCopy = List.from(names)..shuffle();
    return showDialog<void>(
      context: context,
      builder: (BuildContext context) {
        return AlertDialog(
          content: Container(
            margin: const EdgeInsets.all(8),
            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(5),
            width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width / 1.3,
            height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height / 3.5,
            color: Colors.grey.shade900,
            alignment: Alignment.center,
            child: Wrap(
              spacing: 8.0, // gap between adjacent chips
              runSpacing: 4.0, // gap between lines
              children: List<Widget>.generate(
                min(4, namesCopy.length),
                (index) => Text(
                  namesCopy[index],
                  textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                  style: const TextStyle(fontSize: 15),
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
          backgroundColor: Colors.grey.shade900,
        );
      },
    );
  }
```

Comment: First I want to thank you for helping me

But I get an error for duplicating the variable name :

Comment: II have updated my question, please take a look at it @AshishB

Comment: You need to be more specific with how you want to use the random name-picking function. Please show your code where you want the random name

Comment: Sorry, I'm a beginner in the programming world, but I've put the complete code used in three parts
I hope you understand the problem in a simple way @AshishB

Comment: Your code works as it is. I am able to run it normally. The only thing I would change is to disable the get random name button by changing onPressed callback to `onPressed: names.isEmpty ? null : () { showAlertDialog(context);}`

Comment: And also instead of `Row()`, use `Wrap()` to show the texts

Comment: Good but when I press the button it gives duplicate results
It is required to show random names that are not repeated

Comment: I have updated the answer with your requirements. Let me know if this is resolved now

Comment: Yes I got it, the code works as expected, 
I appreciate wasting your time, 
Thanks for your help. @AshishB

Answer (score 0):

Check this one:

```dart
import 'dart:math';
import 'dart:async';

List<String> names = [
  "Alice",
  "Bob",
  "Charlie",
  "David",
  "Eve",
  "Frank",
  "Gina",
  "Henry",
  "Ivy",
  "Joan",
];

Set<String> usedNames = Set();
Duration debounceDelay = Duration(milliseconds: 500);

Timer? debounceTimer;

Random random = Random();

String getRandomName() {
  if (debounceTimer?.isActive ?? false) {
    return;
  }

  debounceTimer = Timer(debounceDelay, () {
    String name;

    do {
      name = names[random.nextInt(names.length)];
    } while (usedNames.contains(name));

    usedNames.add(name);
  });

  return name;
}
```

Comment: Well done but when you repeatedly press the button
The emulator twitches and stops working
I don't know if the problem is with the code @Hamed

Comment: @JabiRAlzahrani I have updated the answer, please check it.

Comment: I get an error returning... `return;` and `return name;` @Hamed

Answer (score 0):

user this [faker](https://pub.dev/packages/faker) package to generate unique credentials name, email and a lots of other data

```
import 'package:faker/faker.dart';

main() {
  var faker = new Faker();

  faker.internet.email();
  // francisco_lebsack@buckridge.com

  faker.internet.ipv6Address();
  // 2450:a5bf:7855:8ce9:3693:58db:50bf:a105

  faker.internet.userName();
  // fiona-ward

  faker.person.name();
  // Fiona Ward

  faker.person.prefix();
  // Mrs.

  faker.person.suffix();
  // Sr.
  
  faker.lorem.sentence();
  // Nec nam aliquam sem et
}
```